# In SQL if where condition does not yield result fetch other rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have Query like this

```
Select * from customers where id = 123 and name like '%tester%';
```

If id : 123 and name : "tester" doesn’t exist in table i should fetch other rows with name "tester" discarding condition "id". if it exists fetch row for that id and name.

Guys i know this is can be handled in program, i want this to be done in my Query, can you please STOP DOWN VOTING and give me the solution if you know!!!

Comment: Can you explain what you'd like to fetch if it doesn't exist? Also, you should add `LIMIT 1` to the query if there can only be one row.

Comment: What other rows should you fetch instead?

Comment: i would like to fetch other rows with consider only name "tester"

Comment: I think this is more of a program issue than sql issue. What programming language are you using?

Comment: Yes i know this can be solved by program but i deliberately need this in my query i am 100% sure there are some techniques to do it!! but i am not able to get them!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   CUSTOMERS 
WHERE  ( ID = 123 
         AND NAME LIKE '%tester%' ) 
        OR ( NAME LIKE '%tester%' 
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                             FROM   CUSTOMERS 
                             WHERE  ID = 123 
                                    AND NAME LIKE '%tester%') )
```

You can find a working example on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3edc/1).

Comment: why use the first "exist" block ? the 2 conditions are still verified by the "AND" before

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE (id = 123 AND name like '%tester%') OR (name LIKE '%tester%') LIMIT 1;
```

It should work then

Answer (score 0):

I gotcha here, check it

```
Select * from customers where id = 3 or name like '%tester%'
     order by id=3 desc limit 1;
```

See you will get all rows that have either id= 3 or name is like tester. From there you will order then by the boolean value (1 if true) by if they == 3. Limiting this to 1 result will get you only the best response.

Likewise if you want to get all results you could remove the limit, assume the top one is the best result. If the first results id is not = 3 then you could say that all the results are just best matches.